# How to set Pandas read_xml to specific node?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, xpath

I am sending a query to an API and receiving an xml repsonse, which I would like to parse into a dataframe. I've recently come across the pd.read_xml option and had a few goes at it so far but can't seem to make it work properly.

My xml looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
 <body>
  <searchretrieveresponse xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/">
   <version>
    1.1
   </version>
   <numberofrecords>
    1
   </numberofrecords>
   <records>
    <record>
     <recordschema>
      oai_dc
     </recordschema>
     <recordpacking>
      xml
     </recordpacking>
     <recorddata>
      <dc xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dnb="http://d-nb.de/standards/dnbterms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <dc:title>
        [Erg.-H.]. Myst IV Revelation
       </dc:title>
       <dc:date>
        2004
       </dc:date>
       <dc:identifier xmlns:tel="http://krait.kb.nl/coop/tel/handbook/telterms.html" xsi:type="tel:ISBN">
        978-3-8272-9125-7 kart. : EUR 16.95, EUR 17.50 (AT)
       </dc:identifier>
       <dc:identifier xmlns:tel="http://krait.kb.nl/coop/tel/handbook/telterms.html" xsi:type="tel:ISBN">
        3-8272-9125-9 kart. : EUR 16.95, EUR 17.50 (AT)
       </dc:identifier>
       <dc:identifier xsi:type="dnb:IDN">
        97274004X
       </dc:identifier>
       <dc:format>
        32 S.
       </dc:format>
       <dc:relation>
        http://d-nb.info/973086416
       </dc:relation>
      </dc>
     </recorddata>
     <recordposition>
      1
     </recordposition>
    </record>
   </records>
   <nextrecordposition>
    2
   </nextrecordposition>
   <echoedsearchretrieverequest>
    <version>
     1.1
    </version>
    <query>
     978-3-8272-9125-7
    </query>
    <xquery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true">
    </xquery>
    <recordschema>
     oai_dc
    </recordschema>
   </echoedsearchretrieverequest>
  </searchretrieveresponse>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the API-response copy-pasted after I pretty-printed it in a Jupyter Notebook.

If I simply print the response via print(r1.content) I get the following:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<searchRetrieveResponse xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/"><version>1.1</version><numberOfRecords>1</numberOfRecords><records><record><recordSchema>oai_dc</recordSchema><recordPacking>xml</recordPacking><recordData><dc xmlns:dnb="http://d-nb.de/standards/dnbterms" xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n  <dc:title>[Erg.-H.]. Myst IV Revelation</dc:title>\n  <dc:date>2004</dc:date>\n  <dc:identifier xmlns:tel="http://krait.kb.nl/coop/tel/handbook/telterms.html" xsi:type="tel:ISBN">978-3-8272-9125-7 kart. : EUR 16.95, EUR 17.50 (AT)</dc:identifier>\n  <dc:identifier xmlns:tel="http://krait.kb.nl/coop/tel/handbook/telterms.html" xsi:type="tel:ISBN">3-8272-9125-9 kart. : EUR 16.95, EUR 17.50 (AT)</dc:identifier>\n  <dc:identifier xsi:type="dnb:IDN">97274004X</dc:identifier>\n  <dc:format>32 S.</dc:format>\n  <dc:relation>http://d-nb.info/973086416</dc:relation>\n</dc></recordData><recordPosition>1</recordPosition></record></records><nextRecordPosition>2</nextRecordPosition><echoedSearchRetrieveRequest><version>1.1</version><query>978-3-8272-9125-7</query><xQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><recordSchema>oai_dc</recordSchema></echoedSearchRetrieveRequest></searchRetrieveResponse>'
```

I have had some success with the following code:

```
df = pd.read_xml(r1.content, namespaces={"xmlns":"http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/", 
                                                               "dc": "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", 
                                                               "dnb": "http://d-nb.de/standards/dnbterms", 
                                                               "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"})
```

However, this only seems to be taking the top-level into account as I receive a dataframe like this:

```
    version     numberOfRecords     record  nextRecordPosition  query   xQuery  recordSchema
0   1.1         NaN                 NaN     NaN                 None    NaN     None
1   NaN         15315.0             NaN     NaN                 None    NaN     None
2   NaN         NaN                 NaN     NaN                 None    NaN     None
3   NaN         NaN                 NaN     11.0                None    NaN     None
4   1.1         NaN                 NaN     NaN                 Händel  NaN     oai_dc
```

Since I am interested in the actual "records" the API returns, I have tried the following:

```
df = pd.read_xml(r1.content, xpath='.//records', namespaces={"xmlns":"http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/", 
                                                               "dc": "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", 
                                                               "dnb": "http://d-nb.de/standards/dnbterms", 
                                                               "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"})
```

but I get an error: `ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes. Be sure row level nodes are in xpath. If document uses namespaces denoted with xmlns, be sure to define namespaces and use them in xpath.`

What I want, in the end, and espcially for responses that include several records, is a dataframe that will list the content of the records. So it should look something like:

```
    dc:title                       dc:date     dc:identifier        
0   [Erg.-H.]. Myst IV Revelation  2004        978-3-8272-9125-7 kart. : EUR 16.95, EUR 17.50 (AT)
```

As far as I know, I have added all namespaces and I have also tried to set xpath to look for "record" instead of "records", or even "dc:title", but so far, I always end up with the error-message as soon as I add the xpath-attribute. What am I doing wrong? I suspect it's got something to do with the correct namespace, but could can't figure out what it is... any help much appreciated!

Comment: The sample xml in your question is not well formed. Can you edit the question and verify you have a simplified, well-formed xml sample, and the expected output from that sample? It will make it much easier to try to answer.

Comment: Hello and thank you, I have included an explanation about the xml-response in the text now and edited it a bit - it should indeed be well formed, but I didn't copy the whole thing but only the beginning.

Comment: Not yet. First, you still need to add a sample of the required output. Second, you should run your xml sample through an XML validator ([for example, this one](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)) and make sure it shows no errors.

Comment: I will have a look about the required output, but I can't do anything about the xml itself, because this is what I get from the API?

Comment: "this is what I get from the API" - very unlikely; check your `r1` again.

Comment: Edited the Code above again - I have now send a query just returns one item (one record) and copy-pasted exactly what I get. Hope this helps clearing things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `read_xml()`[documentation says:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html)

> Note: The etree parser supports limited XPath expressions. For more complex XPath, use lxml which requires installation.

Unfortunately, it seems to me this is one of those situations where a "more complex" xpath is needed... So let's use lxml:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

rec = """[your xml response above]"""
doc = etree.XML(rec.encode())

#now to deal with those pesky namespaces
ns = {"x":"http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/", "y":"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/","z":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"}

#we can now look for the data
rows = []
targets = doc.xpath('//x:record',namespaces=ns)
for target in targets:
    title = target.xpath('//y:title',namespaces=ns)
    date = target.xpath('//y:date',namespaces=ns)
    identifier = target.xpath('//y:identifier[@z:type="tel:ISBN"][1]',namespaces=ns)    
    rows.append([title[0].text.strip(),date[0].text.strip(),identifier[0].text.strip()])

#and, finally, create the dataframe
columns = ['dc:title','dc:date','dc:identifier']
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
     dc:title                       dc:date     dc:identifier
0   [Erg.-H.]. Myst IV Revelation   2004    978-3-8272-9125-7 kart. : EUR 16.95, EUR 17.50...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - so to clarify: You think that it won't be possible to use pd.read_xml with this particular xml-structure? I was hoping that this would be an easier option than using a loop and extracting title, date etc. separately.

Comment: @ssp24 - I'm afraid so. I actually tried for quite a while to do it with `read_xml()` but eventually gave up. I've seen similar issues with deeply nested html and `read_html()`. Maybe someone smarter or more experience can come up with a way. But as noticed, even the documentation tells you that sometimes you have to give up...

Comment: Thank you very much for trying! I have just found an alternative via xmltodict, which helps producing a better looking dataframe than read_xml did, but still on the top level of the nodes. Is there a way to remove a certain "level" of nodes from the xml?